# Add empty element to list

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have list:

```
var Filials = Db.FILIALS.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.PREFIX > 0).Select(x => new { Name = string.Format("{0} {1}", x.PREFIX, x.NAME), FilialId = (Guid?)x.FILIALID }).OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

I need to add empty element to this list. I try this variant:

```
var lst = new[] { new { Name = string.Empty, FilialId = (Guid?)null } }.ToList();
var Filials = Db.FILIALS.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.PREFIX > 0).Select(x => new { Name = string.Format("{0} {1}", x.PREFIX, x.NAME), FilialId = (Guid?)x.FILIALID }).OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
lst = lst.Union(Filials);
```

But get error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable
>   to System.Collection.Generic.List

on last line.

What is correct way to add element to list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace `ToList()` with `AsEnumerable()` in the line that declares `lst`.

The problem is that `lst` is of type `List<anonymous type>` but `Union` returns `IEnumerable<anonymous type>`. An `IEnumerable<T>` can't be assigned to a variable of type `List<T>`.

Using `AsEnumerable()` makes the `lst` variable of type `IEnumerable<anonymous type>`.

Answer (score 3):

Change your last line to **use AddRange method**:

```
var lst = new[] { new { Name = string.Empty, FilialId = (Guid?)null } }.ToList();
var Filials = Db.FILIALS.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.PREFIX > 0).Select(x => new { Name = string.Format("{0} {1}", x.PREFIX, x.NAME), FilialId = (Guid?)x.FILIALID }).OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
lst.AddRange(Filials);
```

Comment: You are 100% right :). I got confused as I copied original code. In fact this is an usual mistake I do...

Comment: @cad Thank you. If remove assigning lst=lst.AddRange(Filials) it is works fine.

Comment: @cad Yes of course. In fact I've tried this variant (that I accepted) before make post with question. But in debug(when we set breakpoint) it is a little strange: If we put mouse over variable 'lst' we don't see lst elements, like in variable 'Filials' for example. Elements in lst in debug mode appears only when we use this list more (For example enumerate in foreach) It baffled me.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [AddRange()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/z883w3dc.aspx) method, it take's `IEnumerable<T>` instead of whatever your type is, `FirstList<T>.Union(SecondList<T>)`.

```
lst.AddRange(yourIEnumerable);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just:

```
Filials.Add(new { Name = string.Empty, FilialId = (Guid?)null })
```

Comment: @cad: That comment doesn't really make sense.

Comment: What I try to say is that lst is a generic and .ADD method accept as parameter only types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1.aspx

Comment: @Jakub Konecki I need empty element at top of list (it is first element of dropdown list).